# VueJS filter return exact match

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a filter function in VueJS and one of the field requires user to choose from dropdown. The options are: `A - Apple, B - Ball, C - Chocolate`. The backend stores the field as A, B and C only. I have no problem returning it from backend and matching it to the full lable, however when filtering, there's a problem. Since user can also input in that field, if for example user inputs 'chain', when choosing 'C - Chocolate' from the dropdown, it will also show 'chain' as the filter output since backend is only returning C. Here is my code:

```
var url = //api call

return http.get(encodeURI(url)).then(res => {

 res.data.forEach((i) => {

 let obj = {}

 for (let field in i) {
  if(field == 'type') {
    let itemType = rootGetters["lookup/getItemType"].find(el => {
      return el.value == i.type
    })
    itemType
      ? (obj[field] = type.label || '') //this is where i map the C to C - Chocolate
      : (obj[field] = i.type)
   }
}
}
}
```

anyone knows how to ensure that the non-related filter (for example, chain here) is not returned? thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to use [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) or [`==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) equality operators, instead of just [`=` assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#assignment_operators).

Comment: More like a comment then answer